# Why the chemical shift value of a proton be negative in proton NMR spectroscopy where TMS is used as standard reference?

Tags: spectroscopy

If there's any possibility of chemical shift value of a proton be negative.And if yes...why..when I am using TMS as a standard reference.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What's so wrong about a negative number, though?

Comment: @Anirban it would just mean the protons are more shielded than those in TMS.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7198/chemical-shift-value-and-proton-nmr-spectroscopy

Answer (score 4):

Is it normal to get negative chemical shifts in $\pu{ppm}$ for NMR analysis?

In general, negative chemical shifts in NMR is possible when you locked it with tetramethylsilane (TMS) as your internal reference, but it is not quite normal with NMR spectra of our day to day chemicals though. If you are not expecting a negative resonance for your compound, then you must calibrate (or make a request to calibrate) your NMR instrument because it may be a calibration problem. In any given case, when you run a NMR spectrum known or unknown compound, you should have a signal that you can identify (such as TMS for example) and whose chemical shift you know. By definition, chemical shift of methyl signal of TMS is exactly to $\pu{0.00 ppm}$. Alternatively, if your solution does not contain TMS, you could set the residual proton signal of the deuterated solvent to its accepted chemical shift (*e.g.*, residual $\ce{CHCl3}$ in $\ce{CDCl3}$ to $\pu{7.28 ppm}$).

Chemical bonds are regions of high electron density and therefore can create local magnetic fields. The best example for that is benzene ring (See the following scheme):

[image: BenzeneRingCurrent]

The induced field by circulating electrons is opposed to the applied external field $\mathrm{B_\circ}$ (Lenz’s law). Electrons within $\sigma$-bonds are not usually able to circulate freely and so the chemical shift will depend on the orientation of the nucleus with respect to the bond. As a result, higher frequency chemical shifts can be obtained for protons outside the ring and lower frequency chemical shifts can be obtained for protons inside the ring. The perfect example is illustrated in following scheme (From Ref.1):

[image: ExampleForNegativePeak]

As you see in the example, inner methyl groups giving negative resonances and outer $\ce{t-Bu-}$ groups having higher field than normal. Hope this simple version make you understand.

**References:**

1. M. Jacquet, F. Lafolet, S. Cobo, F. Loiseau, A. Bakkar, M. Boggio-Pasqua, E. Saint-Aman, G. Royal, “Efficient Photoswitch System Combining a Dimethyldihydropyrene Pyridinium Core and Ruthenium(II) Bis-Terpyridine Entities,” *Inorg. Chem.* **2017**, *56(8)*, 4357–4368 (DOI: 10.1021/acs.inorgchem.6b02861).

Comment: AFAIK modern spectrometers use the solvent deuterium resonance to lock. TMS is just for referencing, not locking

Comment: @orthocresol: Thank you for the comments. I agree. That's what I wanted to say but didn't put right words. :-) It was Friday night and I was rushing to go home. Well done!